# Resample DataFrame at certain time intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a publicly available dataset in pandas which has some air quality statistics by each state of USA.

What I am doing is aggregating the measurements for each of the state and the issue I have is that different states have measurements available across different time periods. So, I am collecting all the data as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
poll = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
poll = poll.groupby(['State', 'Date Local']).mean()

states = pds.index.levels[0]  # All the states
pds_grouped = pds.groupby(level='State')

# Iterate throuugh each of the state and aggregae monthly
for s in states:
     flt = pds_grouped.get_group(s).groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Date Local', freq='M')).agg({'V1': 'mean',
                                                                                           'V2': 'mean',
                                                                                           'V3': 'mean',
                                                                                           'V4': 'mean'})
     print(s, flt.shape, flt.index.min(), flt.index.max(), type(flt))
```

This prints something like:

```
Alabama (30, 4) 2013-12-31 00:00:00 2016-05-31 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Alaska (18, 4) 2014-07-31 00:00:00 2015-12-31 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Arizona (195, 4) 2000-01-31 00:00:00 2016-03-31 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Arkansas (111, 4) 2007-01-31 00:00:00 2016-03-31 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
California (196, 4) 2000-01-31 00:00:00 2016-04-30 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Colorado (195, 4) 2000-01-31 00:00:00 2016-03-31 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Connecticut (117, 4) 2006-04-30 00:00:00 2015-12-31 00:00:00 <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

As you can see they all have different number of measurements and they also span different  time periods. I am trying to create an animation  showing the changes of these contaminants over the whole time and it would be much easier if I can makeeack of these data frames span the same time period and basically fill it with `NaNs` corresponding to the time periods where the measurements are not available for a given state. I have been looking at the `resample` method in pandas but could not figure out how to specify a date range.

Comment: one of your ticks is off in `pd.read_csv(\`dataset.csv')`, which breaks formatting. Maybe `scipy.interpolate` or `DataFrame.resample` are what you're looking for.

Comment: @cripcate Thank you for pointing that out. I tried the resample but I am not sure how to set the date range there.

Comment: can you include some data? then I'll see what I can do. (and others too)

Comment: To use `df.resample` with dates, you need to set the index of the df to be the dates. Then you can pick whatever time interval you want to resample at. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample

Comment: @macaw_9227 Thank you. I think   managed to sort it by using `reindex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
all_dates = poll.index.levels[1]
date_range = pd.date_range(all_dates.min(), all_dates.max(), freq='MS')

flt = (poll.groupby('State')
           .apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(level=1)
                            .resample('MS', on='Date Local')
                            .mean()
                            .reindex(date_range))
       )
```

Comment: TThis does not seem to do what I want. How does it know what the date range it needs to resample on?

Comment: This is amazing! So powerful. Thank you!

Comment: I have a question. How can I get the particular records at the state level from the `flt` object now? It seems I cannot do flt[`Alabama`] for example any more

Comment: `flt.loc['Alabama']`?

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, very new to pandas

Answer (score 0):

So, I did it as follows, which seems to work:

```
import pandas as pd
poll = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
poll = poll.groupby(['State', 'Date Local']).mean()

states = pds.index.levels[0]  # All the states
pds_grouped = pds.groupby(level='State')

# Iterate throuugh each of the state and aggregae monthly
measures = list()
for s in states:
     flt = pds_grouped.get_group(s).groupby(pd.Grouper(level='Date Local', freq='M')).agg({'V1': 'mean',
                                                                                           'V2': 'mean',
                                                                                           'V3': 'mean',
                                                                                           'V4': 'mean'})

    min_time = flt.index.min() if min_time is None else min(min_time, flt.index.min())
    max_time = flt.index.max() if max_time is None else max(max_time, flt.index.max())
    measures.append(flt)

for i in range(len(measures)):
    # Create a date range and reindex.
    dr = pd.date_range(start=min_time, end=max_time, freq='M')
    measures[i] = measures[i].reindex(dr)
```